# "The capes shooting out the furthest into the sea" - grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Would a phrase "the capes shooting out the furthest into the sea" be correct? I need to denote the capes with the most remote tips somehow. Thanks!

Comment: 'Shoot out' in this sense usually implies movement (The volcano shot out masses of lava / Lava shot out of the mouth of the volcano), but a broadened use where the capes are very prominent would be reasonable.  'Projecting' obviously makes sense here, but is not as dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think that's fine to say, especially since you can't really reference a shore line (since a cape is still the mainland).

Instead of "shooting" you could say "jutting".

Comment: Thanks! and would you say "jutting out the furthest" or "jutting the furthest out"?

Comment: I think _jutting out the furthest_ sounds more natural.